# Which hat should our Community user wear?

Tags: discussion, winterbash

For those interested in Hat Season (aka winterbash), it might be interesting to note that the site's automated [@Community user](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) has a couple of hats of its own.

According to [Community, please show some holiday spirit!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159296/135923), moderators can select which of her hats @Community will wear.

In the interest of community-based decision-making (and to prevent mod-hat-sniping), I'm putting this to you: Which hat should we put on Bubbles.SE, the community user?

Please vote for the answer with your favorite hat (or add one if its missing), and one of the moderators will try to update it according to the currently most popular.

Comment: The one for making a meta post with at least one upvote :o?

Comment: Community doesn't have that, but I do :)

Answer (score 7):

[n00b Hat](http://winterba.sh/n00b-hat)

Comment: I like the idea of Community being a n00b.

Comment: n00b it is... at least for now.

Answer (score 2):

[My dear Watson](http://winterba.sh/my-dear-watson)

Answer (score 1):

[L'chaim](http://winterba.sh/lchaim)

Answer (score 1):

[... And I Feel Fine](http://winterba.sh/and-i-feel-fine)